# Continues Cassandra restore testing

Tags: cassandra, backup, restore

I'd would like to set up Continues Cassandra restore testing process.
I have 6 node production cluster and I have incremental backup enabled.
I would like to restore backups on regular basis to a different server.

My question is: do I have to use 6 nodes or can I somehow restore backups from 6 nodes to a single server?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy all SSTables from the 6 nodes to a single node in order to restore them. You'll end up with redundant data depending on your replication factor, but this shouldn't be a problem if you have the required disk space.